# adding cc_binary dependency on a non source/library file

Tags: bazel

I have a rule that generates compiler options and linker.cmd file that should be used for building a binary/library

the cc binary rule currently looks like this:

```
cc_binary(
name = "bsp",
srcs =["src/rtos_main.c"],
data = [":linkfile",":compiler_file"],
copts = ["-@$(execpath :compiler_file)"],
linkopts = ["./$(execpath :linkfile)"],)
```

the problem is that there is no attribute to correctly add the build dependency on targets :compiler_file and :linkfile

as "data" adds them to run dependency, and using "deps" doesn't accept the files as they are neither sources nor binaries.

is there a way around this ?

Comment: I was able to work around this by the following:
for the linker file: modified the generating rule to take an out parameter named "somthing.ld" and adding to "data" the filename as a dependency

for the compiler options:
I modified the generation rule to through a dummy header file a long with the output in the same cmd, added an extra library target the depends on that header file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this by the following:

for the linker file:
modified the generating rule to take an out parameter named "somthing.ld" and adding to "data" the filename as a dependency (bazel restricts linker directives to some extensions)

for the compiler options:
I modified the generation rule to through a dummy header file a long with the output in the same cmd, added an extra library target the depends on that header file.
so the code looks like that

```
xdc_configuro_rule(
srcs = ["..."],
compileropt = "compiler.opt",
linkercmd = "linker.ld",
dummy = "dummy.h"
)
cc_library(
    name = "bspl",
    srcs =[":dummy.h"],
    data = [":compiler.opt"],
    copts = ["-@$(execpath :compiler.opt)"],
)
cc_binary(
    name = "bsp",
    srcs =["src/rtos_main.c"],
    deps = [":bspl"],
    data = [":linker.ld",":compiler.opt"],
    copts = ["-@$(execpath :compiler.opt)"],
    linkopts = ["./$(execpath :linker.ld)"]
)
```

now when ever I need to build bsp, it has to run the compiler/linker options generation scripts.